# How to display a message everytime a single cell is selected in a datagridview?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview, richtextbox

I have four datagridviews and one text box and i want to display a different message for every cell the user might select in one of the dgvs. Any idea is welcome!!!

Comment: More detail would help in this case, do you want to display a message box, display a random message in the text box or I'm thinking, display the contents of the selected cell in the given DGV in the text box?

Comment: the second display a text in a textbox. the text will be some information about the cell the user selected.

Comment: Sorry what is this information how is it linked to the selected cell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I prefer to specify most event handlers in code as below, as opposed to using the GUI which puts the code in the form.designer.cs but that is personal preference

```
public Form1()
 { 
      dataGridView1.CellClick += new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventHandler(populateTextBox());
      dataGridView2.CellClick += new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventHandler(populateTextBox());
      dataGridView3.CellClick += new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventHandler(populateTextBox());
      dataGridView4.CellClick += new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventHandler(populateTextBox());
 }

private void populateTextBox(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    //code here
    //You can use e.Value (cell value data type dependant) if required
}
```

Comment: thank you very much! exactly what i was looking for! just add a description in the answer about the event handler that goes to form.designer.cs and not somewhere insinde form.cs.. took me a while to find out..

Comment: Fair point it is just my preference so I can clearly see everything that is going on by doing it in code saves me time later but cost a little more early on tis' up to the individual.